# Change password PFuser

Tags: ios, parse-platform

How do you let the users change the password, mail, username etc. Any ideas? So far I have this code that you can see below. My problem is that the old data don't show up and I cant update it. I would love some help! :) Thanks a lot

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface SettingsUPEViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>




@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *password2Field;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *mailField;
- (IBAction)updateSave:(id)sender;

@end





#import "SettingsUPEViewController.h"

@interface SettingsUPEViewController ()


@end

@implementation SettingsUPEViewController


NSArray *retriveFormParse;
NSArray *profileArray;


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {

        PFQuery *query= [PFUser query];

        [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser]username]];



        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {

                profileArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];






                // The find succeeded.
                NSLog(@"@%", objects.count);
                // Do something with the found objects
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", objects);
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];



    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    PFQuery *query= [PFUser query];

    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser]username]];

    PFObject *object = [query getFirstObject]; // synchronous request, not ideal, look at getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock

    _usernameField.text = [object valueForKey:@"newname"];
    _passwordField.text = [object valueForKey:@"newpassword"];
    _mailField.text = [object valueForKey:@"newmail"];

    _usernameField.delegate = self;
   _passwordField.delegate = self;
     _mailField.delegate = self;



    _usernameField.delegate = self;
    _passwordField.delegate = self;
    _mailField.delegate = self;



    _usernameField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    _usernameField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    _usernameField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

    _passwordField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    _passwordField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    _passwordField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;


    //_password2Field.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    //_password2Field.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    //_password2Field.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;


    _mailField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    _mailField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
    _mailField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;




    _usernameField.delegate = self;
    _passwordField.delegate = self;
    _mailField.delegate = self;

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 18) ? NO : YES;
}

- (void) retriveFromParse {

    PFQuery *query= [PFUser query];

    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser]username]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog(@"@%", objects.count);
            // Do something with the found objects
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", objects);
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];

}

- (IBAction)updateSave:(id)sender {
    // Create PFObject with recipe information
    PFUser *profile = [PFUser currentUser];
    [profile setObject:_usernameField.text forKey:@"newname"];
    [profile setObject:_passwordField.text forKey:@"newpassword"];
    [profile setObject:_mailField.text forKey:@"newmail"];




    // Upload recipe to Parse
    [profile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {


        if (!error) {
            // Show success message
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload Complete" message:@"Successfully saved profile" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

            // Notify table view to reload the profile from Parse cloud

            // Dismiss the controller
            // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameSet" sender:self];

        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload Failure" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

        }

    }];

}


///    if(![oldPassword.text isEqualToString:[user password]]){
///        [alertMessagePassword setMessage:@"The old password is incorrect!"];
///        [alertMessagePassword show];





#pragma mark - Textfield delegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}




@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't query for the user object. You already have that in `[PFUser currentUser];` You can get fields from this object directly:

```
PFUser curUser = [PFUser currentUser];
_usernameField.text = [curUser valueForKey:@"username"];
```

or simply

```
_usernameField.text = curUser[@"username"];
```

Your `updateSave` method is correct, but I wonder why you're using "newmail", "newpassword" etc. I'm guessing you want to use "password", "username" etc here, unless you want to set a field called "newname" on the user profile...

Comment: Thanks so munch @handsomeguy! 

I changed it to: 

`PFUser *curUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    _usernameField.text = [curUser valueForKey:@"username"];
    _passwordField.text = [curUser valueForKey:@"password"];
    _mailField.text = [curUser valueForKey:@"email"];
    
    _usernameField.text = curUser[@"username"];
    _passwordField.text = curUser[@"password"];
    _mailField.text = curUser[@"email"]; ` 

I also took away newpassword etc. It works better but i get this error: Error: users may not have a password field (Code: 105, Version: 1.2.18)

Comment: I think you're not getting this from the code above, but from the code where you're updating the password? Not reading from it?

Comment: Do you mean this code?

`- (IBAction)updateSave:(id)sender {
    // Create PFObject with recipe information
    PFUser *profile = [PFUser currentUser];
    [profile setObject:_usernameField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [profile setObject:_passwordField.text forKey:@"password"];
    [profile setObject:_mailField.text forKey:@"email"];`
    
-----

Comment: Yes. You said in your previous comment that you now get this error: "Users may not have a password". But that is not from the code you pasted, I'm guessing. It is from the updateSave method. Try replacing [profile setObject:_passwordField.text forKey:@"password"]; with profile.password = _passwordField.text;

Comment: Remember that there is a difference between the default fields like username and password (on which you can use dot notation) and your custom fields.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! :)

Just one more question. If I want the user to type in the old password    before saving is there a good method for that?

Comment: Do you mean to check if the user KNOWS the old password? No special method for it. You would just have to compare it manually and then halt execution if they don't match. That said, it is common to handle password changes separately from other user profile edits, meaning providing a separate page where the user can change their password by typing in the old at the top and then the new password twice. If you handle that as part of the profile editing, you will probably get a lot more problems with users who forget their password (or make mistakes updating it).

Comment: Yes. Ok, thanks for all you tips. Is it something like this?

        
       ` if(![oldPassword.text isEqualToString:[user password]]){
            [alertMessagePassword setMessage:@"The old password is incorrect!"];
            [alertMessagePassword show]; `

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Only this should work:

```
[PFUser currentUser].password = someTextField.text;
```

But some times XCode cache data. Clean your project and then try to build again.

Comment: Thanks I edited my question with the full code so you maybe could see if there is anything I could do..

Comment: Think you got the solution. Good luck. :)